# How can I fix the icon error on 000webhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-hosting

I'm building a site and I'm having problems from getting it from local hosting to public. This is my footer:

[image]

I then uploaded it to 000webhost using all the files and this is what it looks like when it's on 000webhost:

[image]

Edit: Fixed. Apparently I just had to change the rel sheet from http to https

This is the site uploaded to 000webhost:

https://acaschoolgpa.000webhostapp.com/

This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>ACA NHS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="nhsfavicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
<header>
<body>
    <img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li><a href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li><a href="calculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <br>
    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/foodtopeopleschool.jpg')"style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/onground.jpg')">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/givingwater.jpg')">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/holdingcamera.jpg')">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/studentsgroup.jpg')">
            <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>


    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
    <h1 class="Welcome">WELCOME TO THE ACA NHS WEBSITE!</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </center>
    <h2 class="message">Our Message</h2>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"Long before National Honor Society was available in the American Creativity Academy, students sought after an opportunity to create, inspire, and open the doors for creativity. With a heritage of respect to individuality and personal interest, the National Honor Society offered a platform for creation and student ingenuity. Today, the dream of a boy who grew up between the blue walls of ACA turned into reality: he can finally create and enjoy creation for a respected audience!</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;The National Honor Society is a community by students within the campus that works towards creating a better school and local environment. We believe that every act of kindness, no matter how insignificant it may seem, has a drastic impact on a person and starts a ripple of kind-hearted acts among the people. The NHS creates opportunities for its members in volunteering within and off the campus and raising awareness for global issues, which makes them more productive, responsible and engaged citizens. We try to make a difference by inspiring and supporting the people around us whenever we can.</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;The NHS team is more than all of its members; although the impact of one person is limited, working as a team allows us to achieve our goal and leave behind a great mark. We envision a kinder society where people are keen on helping others, and will work until that vision is achieved."</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;- By the NHS Team</p>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>NHS<span>ACA</span></h3>
            <p class="footer-links">Boy's Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nhsb.aca/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                 nhsb.aca&emsp;
                 |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:nhsb.aca@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></a></i>
                nhsb.aca@gmail.com
            </p>
            <p class="footer-links">Girl's Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aca.nhs/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                 aca.nhs&emsp;
                  |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:acanational.hs@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></a></i>
                acanational.hs@gmail.com
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="footer-company-name">© Mohammad al Nusif</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/B3vW2nPkNewZUyxW9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                <p>Boy's Campus map</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/uKS7qgy5P6F8csRK7"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                <p>Girl's Campus map</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Boy's Campus:</span>
                Advisor's email - sali.alkhuraishi@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's email - bahaabed2003@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's email - azoibi17@gmail.com<br>
                <br>
                <span>Girl's Campus:</span>
                Advisor's email - nicole.depew@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's email - kayanalghanim@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's email - skkh03@gmail.com <br>
                <br>
            <div class="footer-icons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}




/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFD750;
}
.Welcome {  
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif; 
    font-size: 62px; 
    font-weight: 800; 
    line-height: 45px; 
    margin: 0 0 24px; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.message {
    font-family: "Great Vibes";
    font-size: 62px; 
    font-weight: 600; 
}

.example_e {
    border: none;
    width: 759px;
    background: #6495ED;
    color: Yellow !important;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.example_e:hover {
    color: #404040 !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.girls-message{
    color: #F0E68C
}

.mySlides {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;

    background-image: var(--background-image);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.mySlides > .numbertext {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.bluebackground{
    background-color: #4169E1;
    margin:0;
}
#messagetext{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px
}

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');




/* The footer is fixed to the bottom of the page */

footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-height:800px){
    footer { position: static; }
    header { padding-top:40px; }
}


.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #2c292f;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    padding: 50px 50px 60px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed .footer-left img{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #e0ac1c;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}


.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #e0ac1c;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}



@media (max-width: 880px) {

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    margin-left: 0;
}

}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cookie-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/cookie/v12/syky-y18lb0tSbf9kgqS.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. the html you provided doesn't seem to be complete. In fact, the footer, which is what you're showing in the pictures provided is not present on the HTML.

Comment: your font awesome is throwing an error in console. Using `http` solves the problem though. http://acaschoolgpa.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: hmmm any idea on how I can fix it on https?

Comment: Hello @MohammadAlNesef. I see that your problem is solved. Would you mind closing your question?